# How can I create a DF by conditionally looking up into another DF, and appending the results horizontally into a new DF?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes - df1 with all the data, and df2 that will be the basis of the lookup into df1. I need to create a 'result' dataframe with one row per row in DF2, where each row should be the original row from DF2, then, horizontally, each of the rows from DF1 that match the ID, and have a date before or equal to the date specified.

I effectively need to find the mini dataframes within DF1 (see code snippet below) that corresponds to the ID and all prior dates for a given row in DF2, then append each row of said mini DF onto the right hand side of DF2.

I understand, as per code snippet 1, how to find the mini_df based on the conditions in DF2, however I'm at a loss as to how to create the new dataframe that contains the appended rows horizontally. Ideally I'd like to specify how many rows I take from said dataframe e.g. if 10 rows match the ID and before-or-on date criteria, I'd like to take say 6 of them.

```
    #code snippet 1 to create mini dataframe from df1 for each row in df2
    mini_df = df1[(df1['ID']=='A0') & (df1['Date']<='20200102')]
```

```python
    df1
      ID1     Date1  Value
    0  A0  20200101    123
    1  A0  20200102    234
    2  A0  20200103    345
    3  A1  20200101    456
    4  A1  20200102    567
    5  A1  20200103    678

    df2
      ID2   Date2
    0  A0  20200103    
    1  A1  20200103    

    result
      ID2   Date2        ID1-1  Date1-1 Value-1     ID1-2  Date1-2 Value-2     ID1-3  Date1-3 Value-3  
    0  A0  20200103        A0  20200101   123        A0   20200102   234        A0   20200103   345   
    1  A1  20200103        A1  20200101   456        A1   20200102   567        A1   20200103   678
```

Code to reproduce the tables:

```python
    import pandas as pd

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID1': ['A0', 'A0','A0', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1'],
                        'Date1': ['20200101', '20200102','20200103', '20200101', '20200102','20200103'],
                        'Value':[123,234,345,456,567,678]})

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID2': ['A0', 'A1'],'Date2': ['20200102', '20200102',],})

    result = pd.DataFrame({'ID2':['A0','A1'],
                           'Date1':['20200102', '20200102',],
                           'ID1-1':['A0','A1'],
                           'Date1-1': ['20200101','20200101'],
                           'Value-1':[123,456],
                           'ID1-2':['A0','A1'],
                           'Date1-2': ['20200102','20200102'],
                           'Value-2':[234,567],
                           'ID1-3':['A0','A1'],
                           'Date1-3': ['20200103','20200103'],
                           'Value-3':[345,678],                       
                          })
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you wanted. I am a bit confused about your example output maybe you can explain more how you got to it.

```
mini_dfs = [df1[(df1['ID1']==row["ID2"]) & (df1['Date1']<=row['Date2'])].head(6).reset_index() 
            for i,row in df2.iterrows()]
for i, df in enumerate(mini_dfs):
    df.columns = map(lambda x:f"{x}-{i+1}", df.columns)
pd.concat(mini_dfs, axis=1)
```

Ouput

```
   index-1 ID1-1   Date1-1  Value-1  index-2 ID1-2   Date1-2  Value-2
0        0    A0  20200101      123        3    A1  20200101      456
1        1    A0  20200102      234        4    A1  20200102      567
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. I'm not at my PC at the moment, but as soon as I am I'll test this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a column to the first df like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
[ 'A0',20200101, 123,1],
[ 'A0',20200102, 234,2],
[ 'A0',20200103, 345,3],
[ 'A1',20200101, 456,1],
[ 'A1',20200102, 567,2],
[ 'A1',20200103, 678,3]
],columns=['ID1','Date1','Value','cat'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
[ 'A0',20200103],
[ 'A1',20200103]
],columns=['ID2','Date2'])
```

You can merge df2 with groups of df from df1:

```
for group in df1.groupby('cat'):
    print(group[1].iloc[0]['cat'])
    df2 = df2.merge(
        group[1][['ID1','Date1','Value']],
        left_on='ID2',
        right_on='ID1',
    )
```

Comment: As per my comment to user2640045, I'm AFK at the moment, and will test your kindly provided method as soon as I can. Thanks again.